# call performSelectorOnMainThread after performSelectorInBackground?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

is it common to call the main thread, at the end of a new thread, to apply the results to the UI? Can't we apply our results from a 'detached' thread? For example, in the sample code ListAdder, we use :

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(threadRecalculateNumbers:) withObject:immutableNumbers];
```

and in the function we come back to the main thread :

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(threadRecalculateDone:) withObject:totalStr waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and the function :

```
- (void)threadRecalculateDone:(NSString *)result
{
    // The user interface is adjusted by a KVO observer on recalculating.
    self.formattedTotal = result;
    self.recalculating = NO;
}
```

Thanks

Paul

Comment: (It is really hard to see what your question is...)

Comment: "Can't we apply our results from a 'detached' thread?" No, the UI can not be updated from other than the main thread. UIKit is not thread-safe.

Comment: @albertamg : thanks albert, so it makes sense that we always call the main thread after having created a detached thread. can you make your answer as a post? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can't we apply our results from a 'detached' thread?

No, the UI can not be updated from other than the main thread. In general, [UIKit is not thread-safe.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an
>   application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes
>   derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your
>   application’s user interface in any way.

This is why it is a common practice to perform a long running task in the background and then call `performSelectorOnMainThread` to update the UI.

Although [beginning with iOS 4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html), drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is thread-safe. Specifically, accessing and manipulating the current graphics stack, drawing images and strings, and usage of color and font objects from secondary threads.